# How do I turn SwitchCompat on or off in code

Tags: android

I want to turn a SwitchCompat widget on or off in code. I mean like when user changes a SwitchCompat from On to Off or otherwise. I want to do this in code. How would I do it?

`SwitchCompat switchCompat = (SwitchCompat) findViewById(R.id.switch_compat);`

Comment: Instead of downvote, answer the question if you can.

Comment: @Kirguduck Did you read the questions date?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As with any `CompoundButton`, you change the checked state of a `SwitchCompat` programmatically [via `setChecked()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/SwitchCompat.html#setChecked(boolean)).

Answer (score 4):

Programatically to change the state of a SwitchCompat control using [`setChecked()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/SwitchCompat.html#setChecked(boolean)) method.

```
SwitchCompat switchCompat = (SwitchCompat) findViewById(R.id.switch_compat);
switchCompat.setChecked(true); //checked.
```

or

```
 switchCompat.setChecked(false); //unchecked.
```

Or you can define the checked state directly inside the layout:

```
   <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
                android:id="@+id/myswitch"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:checked=true/>
```

Answer (score 2):

It is also possible to use `switchCompat.isChecked = false` in Kotlin

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `setChecked(boolean state)` method of the SwitchCompat.

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin

```
bind.btSwitch.isChecked = true
```

if using databinding or:

```
val btSwitch = findViewById<switchCompat>(R.id.specificID)
btSwitch.isChecked = true
```

accesing via findViewById